# Why my washing-machine trips the breaker when turned off?

Tags: circuit-breaker, washing-machine

My 7 year old LG washing machine seems to be tripping the breaker when turned off. Once the cycle is over, the machine turns off and then does not turn on again. I shut off the breaker 5 seconds, turn the breaker on and the machine turns on...

Also, I have tested this: machine stops working, I plug a lamp in the outlet and it works. Then I replug the machine and it works...

Any idea what is the reason for this?

Comment: Is the breaker a simple breaker or GFCI or AFCI? If GFCI and/or AFCI, do you know what mode of tripping occurs?

Comment: It's a simple breaker. Not sure what you mean by mode of tripping

Comment: If it is a simple breaker then the second part doesn't apply. Some people have AFCI breakers (standard in new construction now) and/or GFCI breakers (as an alternative to GFCI receptacles in kitchen, bathroom, etc.). With AFCI and GFCI breakers there is usually some way to determine if the fault was AFCI, GFCI or overcurrent. **Not applicable** with standard breakers.

Comment: If after a seeming trip o'the'breaker you unplug the washing machine, whistle a stanza of your national anthem, and plug it back in does it work? If so, the problem is almost guaranteed to be in the washing machine.

Comment: It is the door sensor switch. Once done with program it should unlock (release) the door. The control board reads that as open door and shuts down. Adjust or replace the door switch

Answer (score 6):

Household breakers do not automatically reset. Therefore, since a lamp plugged in to the same outlet works without touching the breaker, your washing machine is not tripping the breaker.

The problem is in your washing machine, not the breaker. Turning off the breaker causes it to do a full restart, which is sometimes needed for certain problems with the control board. If you have the model number, you can search for it in Google and see if this is a common problem with that model. If I had to guess, you probably need a new control board.

Comment: Good answer. I added a little explanation. I have an occasional problem with my HVAC where it quits but the breaker is fine. Turn it off (breaker or, more conveniently, I have a separate switch for a full shutoff), wait 5 seconds, turn on - and everything works fine for days or weeks. But same concept as this washing machine problem.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact oh man, I have been wasting my time always doing the 20sec count in all such cases

Comment: Thanks guys! I will check what's going on with the machine then.

Answer (score 0):

As you confirmed it is not tripping the breaker, but simply turning it self Off after the washing cycle is completed. It now needs a reset using the power breaker to work again.

That reset will reset the logic on the control board.

What happens when the washing cycle is completed?

It unlocks the door !!!

It is the door sensor switch. You know how washing machine locks the door during operation.

Once done with program it should unlock (release) the door.

The control board reads that as open door and shuts down for safety reason.

Look if the door switch can be adjusted (in or out) if not replace the door switch.

Comment: Not sure how you're certain. If this was the cause, power-cycling the machine wouldn't usually cure it, so I'm not seeing the connection.

Comment: @keshlam expanded my answer

Comment: Better. I still think you are more confident if the specific fix than I would be, but de gustibus.

Comment: @keshlam, Ruskes is _always_ certain of his answers whether there's full information or not. My washer doesn't have a "door lock switch" (I know - I just disassembled the top for a repair last night.)

Comment: I have noticed a certain degree of Dunning-Kruger Effect, yes. Which is why I suspected R might be a 'bot. Might also be a linguistic problem, come to think of it. Whatever. I think there's potential here to be a good contributor, but a bit less certainly would go a long way in that direction.

Comment: Door lock switch is used in front loaders, for possibly obvious reasons.

Comment: Stealing from @harper in another context: "Like Mark Twain said... It's not what you don't know that gets you. It's what you 'know', that just ain't so!"